# Does extending a class in scala inherits auxilary constuctor also?

Tags: scala

I am trying to extend a class which has primary and auxiliary constructor. 
DO my base class has access to auxilary constructors

```
class learnInheritance (speed:Int) {


  val mph: Int = speed
  def race() = println("Racing")

  def this (speed:Int, model:String) {
    this(speed)
    println("Speed of call is " + speed + "and model is " + model)
  }

}

class Car(speed:Int)  extends learnInheritance(speed) {

   override val mph: Int = speed
   override def race() = println("Racing Car")

}

val a = new Car(10,"Maruti")
println("Speed of Car: " + a.mph)
a.race()
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is not any utility function, it is a function that should guarantees that object is fully initialized after it is run.

So if you call `Car` constructor it will return fully initialized `Car` in the process your instance should become fully initialized `learnInheritance` before you start initializing it as `Car`. So you should assume that you can call only one parent constructor.

To deal with this restriction you should require that there is some parent constructor that does all the job, where all other set up some defaults. Then you could call that constructor yourself with your constructor that does all the job, and have other constructors act as utilities with defaults.

```
class Foo(name: String, age: Int) {

  def this(name: String) = this(name, 10)
  def this(age: Int) = this("", age)
}

class Bar(name: String, age: Int) extends Foo(name, age) {
  def this... // bar constructors
}
```

if you cannot do this, then unfortunately you have to pick only one case in your class.

Alternatively, consider that each case is a separate class:

```
class Foo private (name: String, age: Int) {

  def this(name: String) = this(name, 10)
  def this(age: Int) = this("", age)
}

sealed trait Bar { this: Foo =>
  // Bar methods
}
object Bar {
  final class Name(name: String) extends Foo(name) with Bar
  final class Age(age: Int) extends Foo(age) with Bar

  def apply(name: String): Bar = new Name(name)
  def apply(age: String): Bar = new Age(age)
}
```

but this has its own issues.

Most of the time, though, usage of only one parent constructor for everything is not a problem. If it is then we can think for a solution for a particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are not instance methods. That means they are not inherited.